PyQt6 Application Crashes When Window is Moved or Resized During Video Capture with opencv
I am developing an application using PyQt6 that captures live video from a decklink using OpenCV and displays it on a QWidget. The application functions well under normal circumstances. However, I encounter a persistent issue where the application crashes whenever I move or resize the window during video playback. This problem occurs even after trying various methods to handle video thread suspension and resumption during such user interactions.
I am looking for advice or solutions to prevent these crashes, ideally by properly managing the integration between PyQt6 and OpenCV for video capturing in a robust and responsive GUI application. Below is the simplified code snippet that demonstrates the issue, along with details about my environment and the specific errors encountered.
Thank you for any insights or suggestions you might offer.
class VideoThread(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    is_running = True
    is_paused = False  # Aggiungi un flag di pausa

    def __init__(self, video_input=4, fps=30, resolution=(1920, 1080), parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.fps = fps
        self.resolution = resolution
        self.video_input = video_input

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video_input)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, self.resolution[0])
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, self.resolution[1])
        while self.is_running:
            if not self.is_paused:  # Controlla se il thread è in pausa
                ret, cv_img = cap.read()
                if ret:
                    qt_img = self.convert_cv_qt(cv_img)
                    self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(qt_img)
                time.sleep(1 / self.fps)  # Controllo del frame rate
        cap.release()

    def pause(self):
        self.is_paused = True

    def resume(self):
        self.is_paused = False

    def convert_cv_qt(self, cv_img):
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
        bytes_per_line = ch * w
        return QImage(rgb_image.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QImage.Format.Format_RGB888)

    def stop(self):
        self.is_running = False
        self.quit()
        self.wait()

class CameraApp(QWidget):
    ispaused = False
    pixmap: QPixmap
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 640, 480)
        self.initUI()
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()
        self.thread = VideoThread()
        self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)
        self.thread.start()

    def initUI(self):
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if not self.ispaused:
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.pixmap)

    def update_image(self, qt_img):
        self.pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qt_img)
        self.update()

    def event(self, e):
        if e.type() == QEvent.Type.WindowStateChange:
            if self.windowState() & Qt.WindowState.WindowMinimized:
                self.thread.pause()
                self.ispaused = True
            else:
                self.thread.resume()
                self.ispaused = False
        return super().event(e)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.thread.stop()
        super().closeEvent(event)

I have attempted to pause the video capture during window resizing and movement, but this approach did not resolve the issue. I suspect that the problem might be related to how the image frame is updated in the PyQt6 GUI. The application crashes with a segmentation fault, suggesting there might be an issue with how memory is managed or accessed during these operations. Any suggestions on how to handle or debug this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Docs of QImage constructor say: "The buffer must remain valid throughout the life of the QImage". That's certainly not the case in your code, where rgb_image is a local variable that goes out of scope immediately after you called the constructor.

Thank you for the previous suggestions. I implemented the memory handling for QImage as advised, but I am still facing an issue. The application exits suddenly without any error messages when I try to resize or move the window during video playback. Interestingly, when I run the script through the terminal, moving the window causes the program to close silently without any output. However, running it via PyCharm's "Run" yields an exit code of -1073740771 (0xC000041D).

0xC000041D means an unhandled exception occurred. Please [edit] your post instead of putting unformatted code in a comment, it's very difficult to read that.

Why not define a signal with a parameter of the object type for transfering an OpenCV image(NumPy array)? Then, you can convert it into a QImage or QPixmap on the main thread.

After some research and testing on the code, I found a fairly decent solution by creating a class that does not use threads. OpenCV's videocapture is fast enough to return a fullHD numpy array at 60 fps and the optimized conversion between numpy and QPixmap leaving the channel order unchanged (B,G,R) is less than 1/60 of a second and therefore does not slow down execution.

@AlessioMichelassi consider that doing that in the main thread may be an issue on different hardware (possibly, with less performance). A more appropriate usage with threading should probably use a queue/buffer so that the latest image always remains persistent until used (eventually clearing the buffer).

First of all, @musicamante, I would like to thank you for all the support you have given me on other occasions as well. Also, Forza Como, let's hope they have a great season in Serie A.
I have conducted various tests to understand how to achieve a consistent 60 frames per second. My goal is 60fps because it is the standard. Every operation must occur within 0.016 seconds to maintain a constant frame rate.
The solution I found, which currently works best, is to create an object - which for convenience I have defined as QObject - that essentially contains the numpy frame.

The frame within the object is updated every time the external sync object emits a signal and the graphic interface use the getFrame to obtain the last frame.
def capture_frame(self):
if self.camera:
self._frame = self.camera.read()[1]

lua

self.update


@help backtick not working?!

@AlessioMichelassi getting 60fps is the proposed target, it may not always be possible for various reasons (especially when using Python), and if you're not careful enough you may end up with continuous delays that add one on top of the other. That's why you should carefully check how images are accessed and displayed, possibly considering frame skipping. In theory, you should always have one "frame" (the last) that is always immediately accessible in the GUI thread, which may not be the one exactly after the previously shown. It doesn't matter how much time each operation takes, and it »

@AlessioMichelassi » shouldn't affect the precision of the constant frame rate, at least as time reference: every operation should take less than 1/60s, but it could take more or even less. Depending on the situation, the GUI may need to show a constant framerate or as many frames as possible, without delaying in any case, which means that there should always be skipping involved, but also "pausing" (to wait if no new data is available). (ps: you're welcome... but I couldn't care less about soccer ;-) )

You are right: "Depending on the situation." Frame skipping is related to an older approach to handling video that can now be bypassed. With OpenCV, you have access to a numerical matrix in real-time simply by telling the code when to grab it. There is no need to create a separate thread. The threading complexity is significantly reduced because OpenCV handles the real-time video frame capture efficiently.

However, if you have more than one input, for example, 8 cameras, and a limited time frame of 1/60 second, you cannot be sure that a single thread will divide the tasks in time to perform the get operation for all inputs. In such cases, you might need to use multiprocessing instead. Numpy uses Fortran and (Numpy) is already optimized for multiprocessing, so it should work; otherwise, you need another system.

Considering video, a frame with 3 channels at 8-bit and 60 fps (used by the Italian national TV system is interlaced at 1920x540@50). So I mean full HD 60fps.

all of these big words mean nothing. video capture contains buffers/queues everywhere. you are not gonna lose any frames from that camera or capture card that easily.

@Christoph Rackwitz: I understand your point. However, I'd encourage you to try my code to see the practical application and performance. You can find it here: Video Capture Code.
Please make sure to install the required dependencies and use a numpy version less than 2.0. I've also implemented some Monte Carlo simulations to test the average performance.
If you have a capture card, try capturing a chronometer so we can synchronize our testing and discuss the results with a common reference point. Your feedback would be greatly appreciated!

i cannot post images....

@AlessioMichelassi There are two ways of capturing: full content (no frame loss, with possible delays or issues in performance) or on request (possible frame loss depending on the hardware and computation, but no delays or blocking). Full stream analysis and transcoding require the former, playback and average statistics normally use the latter, but consider that the AV device/interface may opt for the second approach on its own. I own a quite old PC (~12yo) and I'm quite convinced that an implementation like the above would have some frame skipping (possibly caused by the Python bottle neck).

@AlessioMichelassi In any case, I suggest you to take your time and devise a proper [mre] (even using your newer approach) that we can easily test. I don't have a video capture card, I've an old DVB-T dongle I haven't used in a while (I bought it just out of curiosity, I don't really watch TV ;-) ), but it can't be directly used as a video source (even if I manage to make some tricky pass-through, it wouldn't be an adequate comparison). I could borrow an HD webcam, though.

Modern cheap video capture cards often use FPGA (Field-Programmable Gate Arrays) to handle the workload. The FPGA performs many of the processing operations in hardware, significantly reducing the load on the computer's CPU. This makes capture cards very efficient and capable of handling high-resolution, high-frame-rate video streams.
The provided code simulates the workload of a capture card by generating and displaying random noise images at 60fps using numpy and PyQt6. While numpy handles image processing efficiently, PyQt6 manages real-time display, demonstrating how high frame rates can be achieved with adequate computational resources.
python

import time
import numpy as np
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *


class SynchObject(QObject):
    """
    A class to emit synchronization signals at a specified FPS.
    """
    # Signal to synchronize frame updates
    synch_SIGNAL = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, fps=60, parent=None):
        """
        Initialize the SynchObject with a specified FPS.

        :param fps: Frames per second
        :param parent: Parent QObject
        """
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.fps = fps
        # Timer to emit sync signals at the desired FPS
        self.syncTimer = QTimer(self)
        self.syncTimer.timeout.connect(self.sync)
        self.syncTimer.start(1000 // fps)  # Set timer interval based on FPS
        self._initialized = True

    def sync(self):
        """
        Emit the synchronization signal.
        """
        self.synch_SIGNAL.emit()


class RandomNoiseImageGenerator(QObject):
    """
    A class to generate frames of random noise and update FPS.
    """

    def __init__(self, synchObject, resolution=QSize(1920, 1080)):
        """
        Initialize the RandomNoiseImageGenerator with a synchronization object and resolution.

        :param synchObject: The SynchObject to synchronize frame generation
        :param resolution: Resolution of the generated frames
        """
        super().__init__()
        self._frame = None
        self.frame_count = 0
        self.last_update_time = time.time()
        self.resolution = resolution
        self.synchObject = synchObject
        self.fps = self.synchObject.fps
        self._frame = self.generate_noise()  # Generate initial noise frame
        self.setPayload(True)

    def setPayload(self, _isPayload):
        """
        Simulate a workload based on the computer's CPU if needed.

        :param _isPayload: Flag to simulate workload
        """
        # Connect the sync signal to the capture_frame slot
        self.synchObject.synch_SIGNAL.connect(self.capture_frame)

    def generate_noise(self):
        """
        Generate a frame of random noise.

        :return: A frame of random noise as a numpy array
        """
        height, width = self.resolution.height(), self.resolution.width()
        return np.ascontiguousarray(np.random.randint(0, 256, (height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8))

    def capture_frame(self):
        """
        Capture a new frame of random noise and update FPS.
        """
        self._frame = self.generate_noise()
        self.update_fps()

    def getFrame(self):
        """
        Get the current frame.

        :return: The current frame or a white frame if no frame is available
        """
        if self._frame is None:
            return np.ones((self.resolution.height(), self.resolution.width(), 3), dtype=np.uint8) * 255
        return self._frame

    def update_fps(self):
        """
        Update the FPS (frames per second) value.
        """
        self.frame_count += 1
        current_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = current_time - self.last_update_time
        if elapsed_time >= 1.0:  # Update FPS every second
            self.fps = self.frame_count / elapsed_time
            self.frame_count = 0
            self.last_update_time = current_time


class VideoApp(QApplication):
    """
    The main PyQt application to display random noise frames and show FPS.
    """

    def __init__(self, argv):
        """
        Initialize the VideoApp with command line arguments.

        :param argv: Command line arguments
        """
        super().__init__(argv)
        self.synchObject = SynchObject(60)  # Set FPS to 60
        self.input1 = RandomNoiseImageGenerator(self.synchObject)
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.viewer = QLabel()
        self.fpsLabel = QLabel()
        self.displayLabel = QLabel()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.fpsLabel)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.displayLabel)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.widget.show()
        self.viewer.setFixedSize(1920, 1080)  # Set viewer size to full HD
        self.uiTimer = QTimer(self)
        self.uiTimer.timeout.connect(self.display_frame)
        self.uiTimer.start(1000 // 30)  # Update UI at 30 FPS
        QTimer.singleShot(10000, self.stop_app)  # Stop the app after 10 seconds

    def display_frame(self):
        """
        Display the current frame and update FPS and display time.
        """
        frame = self.input1.getFrame()
        if frame is not None and frame.size != 0:
            start_time = time.time()
            # Convert the frame to QImage and display it
            image = QImage(frame.data, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format.Format_BGR888)
            self.viewer.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
            display_time = time.time() - start_time
            self.displayLabel.setText(f"Frame displayed in {display_time:.6f} seconds")
            self.fpsLabel.setText(f"FPS: {self.input1.fps:.2f}")

    def stop_app(self):
        """
        Print the average FPS and exit the application.
        """
        print(f"Media FPS: {self.input1.fps:.2f}")
        self.exit()


# Example usage of the VideoApp class

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys


    def main():
        app = VideoApp(sys.argv)
        app.exec()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import cProfile
        import pstats
        import io

        # Profile the main function to analyze performance
        pr = cProfile.Profile()
        pr.enable()
        main()
        pr.disable()

        # Use pstats to sort and print the profiling results
        s = io.StringIO()
        sortby = 'cumulative'
        ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=s).sort_stats(sortby)
        ps.print_stats()
        print(s.getvalue())

# cProfile.Profile() is used to profile the performance of the application. It records the execution time of different functions.
# pstats is used to analyze and sort the profiling results. It helps to identify which parts of the code are consuming the most time.


It is possible to modify the code to capture frames using a thread. However, in my experience, I found that counterintuitively it is better not to use threading for this purpose. You can compare the data provided by pstats to analyze performance differences.
Additionally, you can perform visual tests to compare results. In this example, we generate noise, but if you capture and reproduce frames from a camera recording a stopwatch, the goal is to ensure that the time displayed on the screen matches the time on the stopwatch.
